# Entity Framework in an N-tier online game

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6, n-tier-architecture, online-game

I am trying to find a good design pattern for an online game (for an educational project, not commercial).

Lets say I have a table of Players, and a table of Maps in my DB.
So the entity framework auto-generated these Model classes:

```
public partial class Map
{
    public Map()
    {
        this.Players = new HashSet<Player>();
    }

    public int MapID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}


public partial class Character
{
    public int CharacterID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MapID { get; set; }

    public virtual Map Map { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need a "Controller" Player and Map classes, that will hold state information (Like position on the map):

```
public class MapController
{
    private Map _map;
}
public class PlayerContoller
{
    private Player _player;
    private int _locationX;
    private int _locationY;
}
```

Now I want to add a MapController property to PlayerController (that will return the MapController of the map the player is at).

I can get the Map object by using `this._player.Map` but now to find the MapContoller I have to implement my own list of MapControllers and search through that list. Something like:

```
public class PlayerContoller
{
    private Player _player;
    private int _locationX;
    private int _locationY;

    public MapController MapController
    {
        get { globalListOfMapControllers.Search(this._player.Map); }
    }
}
```

Which is kind of ugly. I would like to have a nicer way to find it out, that will be already implemented for me. (Just like Player.Map)
Moreover, it is a redundant search, because `Player.Map` already searches the Map objects using `Player.MapID`.

Can anyone think of a better design for a system like this one?

Thank you,
Bugale.